# FLVPlayback: No repeated play of a video after VideoEvent.COMPLETE

Tags: flash, flvplayback

Let's keep it short and sweet:

Actionscript 3.0.

I dynamically add a FLVPlayback component (var flvcomp;) to my Flash movie, supply it with a custom skin and on VideoEvent.READY my script fires:

```
flvcomp.play();
```

All is fine, the video plays.

Once it reaches its end (there's no stop button in my skin), the VideoEvent.COMPLETE handler makes a custom play-button visible. When this one is user-clicked the AS fires again: flvcomp.play();

BTW:

```
flvcomp.autoRewind = true;
```

Now, when the play-button is pressed in this situation, I expect the video to replay. Instead, it seems to hang for about 3 seconds (not playing at all) and then the VideoEvent.COMPLETE is triggered again. The play-button re-appears. This goes on forever.

The Actionscript behind this is a 180 lines long fabrication which I wrote about 3 years ago, has been refined a couple of times, and used to work fine so far in this particular aspect. Now it throws up this problem.

The videos concerned are in FLV and MP4 (H.264) format. The FLVPlayback is version 2.1.0.23.

Has somebody experienced the same issue and - hopefully - found a workaround? Any other vaguely related advice is appreciated as well.

Comment: I'd recommend just going with making your own custom player using `NetStream` and `Video` objects. Here is **[a tutorial](http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/06/03/tutorial-playing-flv-video-in-plain-as3-part-1/)** .One week for learning that method is better than one week of struggling with this.. and you get more control and once you master it and later the `appendBytes` methods where you can do anything (adjust speed, watch frame-by-frame, play unsupported codecs etc)

Comment: Thanks VC.One for your suggestion. If today would be 3 years ago I would dive into NetStream and Video objects and make my own custom player instead of using the increasingly buggy FLVPlayback component. But today - 2015 - I personally believe that Flash in general is on the way out. I'd rather focus on HTML5 video matters. It's only that I got this client who wants me to re-work this Flash application from 2012. And the budget is tight, hence I'm after a quick fix and not investing too much energy/time in a technology that is doomed anyway.